# VIM functions: when to use "normal", when to use "exec" and when to use nothing?

Tags: function, vim

In studying VIM functions to learn to write my own I see that commands are sometimes written [preceded with the keyword `normal`](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip1296):

```
normal mz
```

Sometimes with the `normal` [wrapped in an `exec`](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip1087):

```
exec "normal mk"
```

Or sometimes [alone on the line](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Preview_HTML_files_quickly);

```
0d
```

Where in the fine manual is this addressed?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You're getting confused with the various modes. More specifically, the command
mode and normal mode.

Command mode  is where the  ex commands are  applied, the commands  that begin
with a colon. VimScript files are just a sequence of ex commands.

When you need to perform a normal mode command while in ex mode (command mode)
you use the  `:normal` ex command, which executes the  arguments as they would
be in normal mode.

When you execute command directly, well, you're executing it directly. In your
example, the `:d`  command was used with  a range. That's not the  same as the
`d` key in  normal mode, that's another entirely different  command. Check the
help for `:d` and `d` (the normal command).

The `:execute` is useful to build a command as a string and *execute* it as an
ex  command. In  your example,  it's useless.  But it  becomes handy  in other
cases, as an example when you have  a variable holding a line number and wants
to use its value in a command:

```
:let i=4
:exec "2," . i . "d"
```

Which is just the same as

```
:2,4d
```

Comment: I see, thanks. I was unaware of the difference between Command and Normal modes.

Comment: Are searches with `?` considered Normal or Command mode? Neither seem to be working for me!

Comment: @dotancohen Actually, the full definition of command mode includes ex-commands (:), search commands (/ and ?) and the filter command (!). What exactly isn't working? :-P

Comment: You may like reading chapters 28, 29 and 30 in Steve Losh's book: http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/

Comment: @sidyll There are no separate searches in command mode. There is something that looks like “empty command”: “go to last line in range”. Search you are refering to is a part of range, but doing `:1<CR>`, `:'<<CR>` and `:$<CR>` act as expected: go to first line, go to start of visual selection and go to last line. Same applies for filter command: `:!` is just a weird command name. If you are talking about different ways to start command-line mode then you missed various uses of expression register (mainly `<C-r>=`), `input()`, `<C-\>e` (mainly used in mappings) and, probably, something else.

Comment: But in the last case (you are talking about different ways of getting command mode) there is no separate mode for `!`: it just starts `:` command mode variant with a bit of prepopulated symbols.

Comment: @darcyparker: Thanks, that is a great resource!

Comment: @ZyX Well, I was quoting the help for `Cmdline-mode` — and I actually checked that to get a correct definition. Thanks for clarifying, indeed these four boil down to the same thing, and I never though about search being solely a range (though I used it as range many times…)

Comment: People also use `execute "normal ..."` because if you use just `normal` you can't press any special keys like `<cr>`. The easiest solution is to put it a string and execute it.

Answer (score 10):

Well let's ask Vim's extensive built-in help system, which you can access by typing `:h` followed by the command or keyword you're interested in:

#### `:h norm`

> `:norm[al][!] {commands}`
>
> Execute Normal mode commands `{commands}`.  This makes it possible to execute Normal mode commands typed on the command-line. ...

So in other words, `normal mz` in a script is equivalent to typing `mz` in normal mode.

#### `:h exec`

> `:exe[cute] {expr1} ..`
>
> Executes the string that results from the evaluation of `{expr1}` as an Ex command. ...

It's not clear to my why the author of the linked script uses `exec "normal mk"` instead of `normal mk` (`mk` in normal mode just sets a mark called "k"). The docs do offer this, though:

> `:execute` is also a nice way to avoid having to type control characters in a Vim script for a `:normal` command:
>
> ```
> :execute "normal ixxx\<Esc>"
> ```
>
> This has an `<Esc>` character, see `|expr-string|`.

As for `0d`, some Ex (command-line) commands can be given a range of line numbers to execute on. `0` is usually interpreted as `1`, since Vim line numbering starts at 1, not 0, so `:0d` (and `:1d`) simply deletes the first line. `:2,4d` would delete the second, third, and fourth lines. See **`:h cmdline-ranges`** for more details.

Comment: Thank you, the `exec` is now clear. I also very much appreciate the reference to the manual, I will spend some time going through the relevant section.

Comment: it seems that function will execute a <esc> after it's called.